# Array Code is not giving giving expected output

Tags: c, for-loop, debugging

I came across this problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sub[50], i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 48; i++);
    {
        sub[i] = i;
        printf("\n%d", sub[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Though I expected the output to be all numbers from 0 to 48, strangely enough it prints 49. Any explanations?

Comment: You should normally end outputs with a newline rather than putting the newline at the beginning of the format string.  That is, however, unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Your loop has a semicolon at the end of the `for` line. The printing is only done once, after the loop exits.  At that point, `i` is no longer `<= 48`; it is 49.

Comment: Dodge tedious typo bugs like this by not using dinosaur style C. Instead use `for(int i=0; ...` and you would never have written the bug. This is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
  for (i = 0; i <= 48; i++);
```

should be

```
  for (i = 0; i <= 48; i++)
                        // ^-------no ; here
```

Otherwise, the block inside the `{}` is not considered as the loop body, and executes only after the loop has finished execution (with an empty set of statements, only increasing the value of `i`), and the value of `i` is actually `49`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove semicolon at the end of for loop

You expected code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sub[50], i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 48; i++)
    {
        sub[i] = i;
        printf("\n%d", sub[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But your code runs like that

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sub[50], i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 48; i++);
    // here i is already 49
    {
        sub[i] = i;
        printf("\n%d", sub[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So below code only runs 1 time and at that time i is 49

```
        sub[i] = i;
        printf("\n%d", sub[i]);
```